# FRDM K64-F GPIO Pins

Tags: gpio, pins, mbed

I am building a small system to allow the FRDM K64-F to control some motors via a H-Bridge. My problem is I am sturggling to understand the documentation provided for the microcontroller.

Can anyone with some knowledge of the board provide information on what are the main GPIO pins of this board?

http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/user_guide/FRDMK64FUG.pdf

Comment: Look at Figure 18 in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [developer.mbed.org](http://developer.mbed.org) to program the K64F you could use this page (https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/FRDM-K64F/) and all its examples to get started really quick. Note that every blue box on the pinmap is a GPIO pin.